# Recommended way of waiting on an Apollo query before rendering the next page?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, apollo-client

When using the [Apollo module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module) in a Nuxt app, the default behavior when changing routes is to render the new page immediately, before data has been fetched via Apollo.

This results in some pretty janky rendering experiences where the page does a partial render and very soon after completes rendering with data from the server, making everything on the page shift due to the changing size of components that now have data. This looks pretty bad because the data actually comes back fairly quickly, so it would be fine to wait for the data to return before rendering the new route.

What's the recommended way of waiting on the Apollo queries on a page (and its subcomponents) to complete before rendering the page?

(There's [a related question](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-apollo/issues/598) that's not specific to Nuxt, but I'm not sure how to translate the recommendation to a Nuxt app.)

I'd love to see a code example of using `beforeRouteEnter` to fetch data via Apollo and only entering the route once the data is fetched.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used this module before, but it should be like any other async action you want to perform before page rendering in Nuxt.

It only depends if you want to pre-fill the store:
https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module#nuxtserverinit
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action

or only one page:
https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module#asyncdatafetch-method-of-page-component
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data

You can use async/await or promises if you have more than one request before page should be rendered.

When async actions are finished, Nuxt starts rendering the page. This works for SSR and if you navigate to pages on the client (nuxtServerInit will only fire once when real request is made, not when navigating on client side).

Side note: beforeRouteEnter is usually used, to validate params and check if the route is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use the loading attribute:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="!this.$apollo.loading">
        Your product: {{product}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "Product",
    apollo: {
        product: {
            query: productQuery,
            variables() {
                return {
                    productId: this.productId
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: this doesn't quite do what I'm asking for, which is to wait on the previous page before changing to the next page. this solution, I think, will immediately change to the new page, but it will appear blank due to the `v-if`. if that's not the case, would you mind posting a Codepen/CodeSandbox/etc showing how this would work?

Answer (score 0):

did you try disabling the prefetch?

`prefetch: false`

Answer (score 0):

It's a legacy vue2 question, but I have found a solution to it.

Somewhere in the Vue preloader, you can add to `to` via `router.beforeEach` `apolloClient` so you may use it everywhere where you can access to it (almost everywhere):

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  to.params.apolloClient = client
}
```

In component, you may use `to.params.apolloClient`:

```js
  beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    to.params.apolloClient
      .query({
        query: PARTNERS
      })
      .then(({ data: { partners } }) => {
        to.params.partners = partners
        next()
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        captureException(e)
        next()
      })
  },
```

In data you will be able to get it via:

```
data () {
  this.$route.params.partners
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm unfamiliar with Apollo, but I think this is what you are looking for:

```js
// Router.js
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next)
{
    executeSomeApolloPromise().then((data) => {
        // The promise has now been complete; continue to the component.
        next((vm) => {
            // You have access here to the component instance via `vm`.
            // Note that `beforeRouteEnter` is the only guard that has this.
            vm.someApolloData = data;
        });
    });
}
```

See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard

Comment: This looks promising. I'm going to give this a try.

Comment: The problem I'm running into is: how do I get access to $apollo if I don't have aves to the Vue instance?

Comment: you dont. so you must have access to the Vue instance.